# Changing View Engine after Project has been created

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a project in asp.net mvc4 and set its View Engine to ASPX. Now, I want to change the View Engine to Razor. How to do that? I don't want to create a new project. I want to use existing project to change the View Engine. Can we change the View Engine from Properties or some how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

Add it to Application_Start in global.asax.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'll check whether it helps.