# <% %> is not working in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC. Now I am learning with VS2010, ASP.NET MVC 4.

`<% %>` is not working for me. It is tedious for me to use `@`.

If i write large code with lot of `if{}` then `<%` will be useful. 
Can you please help me how to write with `<% %>`

I need like this:

```
The customer id is <%= Model.Id %> <br />

The customer Code is <%= Model.CustomerCode %> <br />

<% if (Model.Amount > 100) {%>
This is a priveleged customer
<% } else{ %>
This is a normal customer
<%} %>
```

But I am able to use like this only:

```
<div>
@{
    if(Model.Amount > 70000.00) 
    {
        Response.Write("This is a Privelleged Customer"); <br />
    }
    else
    {  
        Response.Write("This is a Normal Customer"); <br />
    }
}   
The Customer Id is: @Model.Id <br />
The Customer Name is: @Model.Code <br />
</div>
```

Comment: It's because the render engine you are using is Razor. I think when you set up the project you can choose which engine to use. You can do this after you've set it up though, see this SO post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563811/changing-view-engine-after-project-has-been-created - you will just need to change it *from* Razor to the ASPX one (a bit of Internet searching will throw up what you need)

Comment: Why are you using Response.Write in your Razor code? You don't need to do this. Is this why you don't like Razor?

Comment: @Liam - I think it's that the OP is used to writing in the ASPX view engine. To overcome having to use `Response.Write()` function, you could just write some HTML markup within the curly braces instead

Comment: You could change all of your razor code into `@if(Model.Amount > 70000.00){ <text>This is a Privelleged Customer</text> } else { <text>This is a Normal Customer</text> }` This seems a lot simplar to me than your old style MVC code

Answer (score 4):

Do you really think the former is more readable than the latter? I don't. Razor syntax is here to stay, so you'd better get used to it and drop everything you know about ASP.NET WebForms. Also, why are you using the archaic `Response.Write()`?

A Razor-like implementation of your code would look like this:

```
@if(Model.Amount > 70000.00)
{
    <text>This is a Priveleged Customer</text><br />
}
else
{  
    <text>This is a Normal Customer</text><br />
}
```

Which is pretty readable if you ask me. See [ASP.NET MVC View Engine Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison) for a comparison of view engines, each providing their own syntax with according pros and cons.

If you really insist on the WebForms syntax, apply the WebFormViewEngine as explained in [Changing View Engine after Project has been created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563811/changing-view-engine-after-project-has-been-created).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [CodeCaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40149189/6240567) - the Razor view engine is here to stay and is certainly more readable than ASPX.

However, if you do *really* need to change it, you can.

Go into `Global.asax.cs` and find the `Application_Start()` method.

In there, add the following code:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine());
```

And this will revert you to using the old-style view engine.

Also, you can choose which engine to use when you first set up the project - for when you set them up in future.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use @: to display the text inside server tags

```
<div>
@{
if(Model.Amount > 70000.00) 
{
 @:This is a Privelleged Customer <br />
}
else
{  
    @:This is a Normal Customer <br />
}
}   
The Customer Id is: @Model.Id <br />
The Customer Name is: @Model.Code <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add another property to your model (if you are able to) and handle the logic there:

```
public string CustomerText
{
   get
   {
       return Amount > 70000.00 ? "This is a Priveleged Customer" : "This is a Normal Customer";
   }
}
```

And consume it in your view:

```
<text>@Model.CustomerText</text><br />
```

Comment: Or better yet put this logic into the controller and populate a value in a viewModel.

Comment: @Liam - indeed!